# geolocator.reverse() TypeError: reverse() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

in this code in pyspark

```
pip install geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = 'app')
import pandas as pd 
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def direccion_func(lat, lon):
    dir = geolocator.reverse(lat, lon).address
    return dir

direccion = udf(direccion_func, StringType())

paradasRuta1DF = paradasRuta1DF.withColumn('Direccion', direccion_func(F.col("Latitud"), F.col("Longitud")))
```

I get the error -> TypeError: reverse() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I don´t understand it, because i get two arguments, Latitud y Longitud

Thanks for help

---

I have also tried:

```
    def direccion_func(coordenadas):
           dir = geolocator.reverse(coordenadas)
           return dir.address
    
        direccion = pandas_udf(direccion_func, returnType = StringType())
    
       paradasRuta1DF = 

paradasRuta1DF.withColumn('Direccion',direccion_func(F.col("LatLong")))
```

and the error appears: TypeError: Failed to create Point instance from Column<b'LatLong'>

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you get this error is because the **reverse** function should take as argument either a tuple or a list containing the given coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know for the userAgent "app", but for the userAgent "GetLoc" the lat and long are in the same string inside the reverse() method, like this

```
location = f'{Long}, {Lat}'
geoLoc = Nominatim(user_agent="GetLoc")
locname = geoLoc.reverse(location)
```

It works for me, at least with the "GetLoc" userAgent